# how to retrieve a file from parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Hi i'm using the Parse JavaScript API and i just cant for the life of me figure out how to retrieve a parse file. I can get it to save fine just no matter what i do i cant get the file or even just a url to it.
Basically I want a user to save an image on an update page and for the image to appear on their profile page.

```
var Fiftyfifty = Parse.Object.extend("fiftyfifty");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Fiftyfifty);
    query.equalTo("objectId", "xlHFP1QYmq");
    query.first({
        success: function (results) {
            // The object was retrieved successfully.
            //alert("found");
            //alert("Successfully retrieved " + results.attributes.fiftyfiftyfile.url + " ");
            //alert(fiftyfifty.attributes.fiftyfiftyfile.toString());
            //var object = (fiftyfifty.id());
            //var imageFile = object.get('fiftyfifty');
            //var imageURL = imageFile.url();
            //$('poster').src = results.attributes.fiftyfiftyfile.toString();
            //var profilePhoto = results.get("fiftyfiftyfile");
            //$("poster")[0].src = profilePhoto.url();

            //document.getElementById("poster").src = results.attributes.fiftyfiftyfile.toString();



            //document.getElementById("poster").innerHTML = ((fiftyfifty.url()));
        },
        error: function (object, error) {
            // The object was not retrieved successfully.
            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
            alert("fail");
        }
    });
```

The commented out code is some stuff I tried but the best I could get was [object object]
mostly I just get some form of "cannot set property of undefined" error in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your column name of uploaded file is

fiftyfiftyfile then

you can get url of uploaded file is as follows:

```
fiftyfiftyfile._url
```

Comment: this worked thanks. would you be able to maybe link or explain why the underscore before url.